# Phpseclib generated RSA keys in a session (with C# client)

Tags: c#, php, server, rsa, phpseclib

I want to make an RSA communication between PHP and C#.
I try to use the [phpseclib](https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib) but I have some problems.

This is how I create the keys on the server:

```
$rsa = new Crypt_RSA();
extract($rsa->createKey());
$_SESSION['RSAPubKey'] = $publickey;
$_SESSION['RSAPrivKey'] = $privatekey;
echo $_SESSION['RSAPubKey']; //here I send the public key to the client
```

This is the C# client:

```
string valasz = RequestPOST(Program.SzerverDomain + "/Teszt1/SZCShost.php", "hostmuv=biztkapcsrsakulcs");
```

Here is the "RequestPOST()" method:

```
    static CookieContainer cookieJar = new CookieContainer();
    public static string RequestPOST(String URL, string postData)
    {

        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(Uri.EscapeUriString(URL));
        request.CookieContainer = cookieJar;

        var data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);

        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        request.ContentLength = data.Length;

        using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        }

        var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

        var responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();

        return responseString.Replace("<br>", "\n").Replace("<br/>", "\n");
    }
```

Now I have the keys, but I can not use them. I tried to load them, but I didn't succeed in php and in C# too.
If you used phpseclib with C#, would you be so kind to show me your source codes? Or could you help me in another ways?

Thank you for your kindness!

Comment: Can you post the code that you've written to actually load the key? As is you've posted code that'll get the response from the PHP script and then return it. That said, here's some code: http://csharp-tricks-en.blogspot.de/2015/04/rsa-with-c-and-php.html The phpseclib stuff is out of date - modern versions of phpseclib have built in support for XML keys. But the C# can maybe help you.

Comment: After all, I used the [updated version of that article](http://csharp-tricks-en.blogspot.hu/2015/04/rsa-with-c-and-php_27.html).
It works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution came from [neubert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/569976/neubert)'s comment:

> As is you've posted code that'll get the response from the PHP script and then return it. That said, here's some code: http://csharp-tricks-en.blogspot.de/2015/04/rsa-with-c-and-php.html The phpseclib stuff is out of date - modern versions of phpseclib have built in support for XML keys. But the C# can maybe help you.

I just post it here to find it.

[This article](http://csharp-tricks-en.blogspot.hu/2015/04/rsa-with-c-and-php_27.html) explains the method.